# Multiplicity constraints for 4-ary relations and more in Alloy

Tags: alloy

Suppose I have the following signatures defined:

```
sig B,C,D{}
```

Now when I write

```
sig A{
    r:  B one ->  lone  C
}
```

it means that `{all a:A | A.r in B one ->  lone  C}`; that is, for each a:A, A.r is a binary relation with the multiplicity *one* at B side and *lone* at C side .

Now suppose that I define :

```
sig A{
    r:  B one ->  lone  C some -> lone D
}
```

it might be said that it means `{all a:A | A.r in B one ->  lone  C some -> lone D}`; but what does this mean precisely?

I looked at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501430/multiplicities-in-ternary-relations), but it does not seem to adress the above question. At least it is still confusing to me how it is interpreted?

Answer (score 0):

> it means `all a:A | a.r in B one ->  lone  C some -> lone D`; but what does this mean precisely?

I'm not an Alloy expert, but in my understanding it means: If `r` is non-empty, its form follows the multiplicity constraints like this:

```
assert implications {
  some r implies all a: A |
   (all c: C | one a.r.D.c)  // exactly one B for every C
   && (all b: B | lone a.r[b])  // at most one C for every B
   && (all d: D | some a.r.d)  // some C for every D
   && (all c: C | lone a.r[B][c]) // at most one D for every C
}

check implications for 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you think about the constraint and how the associativity of `->` applies to that relation, it becomes more clear.
In this particular case

```
  sig A { r:  B one -> lone C some -> lone D }
```

is equivalent to writting

```
  sig A { r:  B one -> lone (C some -> lone D) }
```

which means that there is one `B` related to at most one relation that has the form of `(C some -> lone D)`.

This equivalence can be checked with

```
equivalence1: check {
    (all a: A | a.r in B one -> lone C some -> lone D) implies
    (all a: A | a.r in B one -> lone (C some -> lone D))
}
```

which should hold, while e.g.

```
equivalence2: check {
    (all a: A | a.r in B one -> lone C some -> lone D) implies
    (all a: A | a.r in (B one -> lone C) some -> lone D)
}
```

should not hold.